# FakeUsedError: 'post' , No stub was found which matches the argument of this method call

Tags: flutter, mockito

In this code I tried to build a `Mock` testcase form a `Datasource`, I used `Mockito` package

```
@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<Dio>()])
void main() {
  group(
    "LoginRemoteDataSourceImpl",
    () {
      late LoginRemoteDataSourceImpl datasource;
      late MockDio mockDio;

      setUp(() {
        mockDio = MockDio();
        datasource = LoginRemoteDataSourceImpl(dio: mockDio);
      });

      void setUpMockDio200() {
        when(
          mockDio.post(
            kApiLogin,
            data: {
              "email": "test@test.test",
              "password": "testPassword",
            },
            options: Options(headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
          ),
        ).thenAnswer(
          (_) async => Response(
            statusCode: 200,
            data: {
              "token": "testtokenfdjasfjdasklfjadksjflasj",
              "user": {
                "id": 1,
                "username": "test",
                "email": "test@test.test",
                "date_joined": "2023-08-0",
                "userprofile": {
                  "fullname": "test",
                  "biography": "this is just a test",
                  "profile_picture": "/images/profile_picture.jpeg",
                  "location": {"latitude": 123, "longitude": 123}
                }
              }
            },
            requestOptions: RequestOptions(),
          ),
        );
      }

      test(
        "should login",
        () async {
          // setup mock dio
          setUpMockDio200();

          final result = await datasource.login(
            email: "test@test.test",
            password: "testPassword",
          );

          expect(result, isA<LoginResponseModel>());
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

When I tested this test case, I got this error:

> FakeUsedError: 'post'
> No stub was found which matches the argument of this method call:
> post('https://example.com/login/', {data: {email: test@test.test,
> password: >testPassword}, queryParameters: null, options: Instance of 'Options',
> cancelToken: null, >onSendProgress: null, onReceiveProgress: null})
>
> A fake object was created for this call, in the hope that it won't be ever accessed.
> Here is the stack trace where 'post' was called:
> enter code hereHowever, member 'statusCode' of the created fake object was accessed.
> Add a stub for MockDio.post using Mockito's 'when' API.

Comment: What is the `Options` class?  Does it provide an `operator ==`?  If not, then two `Options` instances will never compare equal, and consequently your stub will never match an actual invocation.

Comment: Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I don't know what you need explained.  When you register a stub, the stub will be invoked only when the arguments match *exactly*, and the way to determine if an object matches another object for usually is to compare them for equality.  The default implementation for `==` checks only for object identity.